# Is yogurt affected by human emotions?

Tags: physiology, experiments, emotions

The documentary *[I Am](http://www.iamthedoc.com/)* ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_(2010_American_documentary_film))) ([YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8EGwlnygOc)) makes a number of claims, including that more signals are sent from the heart to the brain than vice-versa, and that the your emotion or mood can have an effect on objects around you.

In particular, a test is shown measuring signals sent out by yogurt, and showing it is affected by emotions.

This seems far-fetched. Does this test demonstrate yogurt is directly affected by the emotions of people around it?

Comment: The original question was too broad, as apparently the documentary makes many claims. I edited it to focus on one of them. For those of us who haven't seen the movie, it would be helpful to detail the claim more precisely. (The yogurt in my fridge is affected by my emotions; when I feel hunger it gets consumed. However, I suspect that doesn't match the claims made.)

Comment: Look up "Primary perception". The Mythbusters replicated the results of the original Cleve Backster experiments and found that outside influences on the polygraph were responsible for the results, not any changes in the plant. Further testing with an EEG could obtain no significant differences in activity from a sample of active-culture yogurt, given several shocks administered via a Taser to Tory, and even a mass bacterial genocide of pouring boiling water into a second test tube of the same yogurt.

Comment: The world really will be a poorer place if 'psychic yoghurt' turns out not to be a real thing.

Comment: In the film, i found it disconcerting to see that they never showed both the yogurt and the voltmeter in the same frame of view, while it was apparently being influenced. Seems like a bit of an opportunity for some 'sleight of hand'.

Comment: @Nathan Even if they had, would it prove anything?  There are still many easy ways to manipulate if that is the intent.  The question is really... is that the intent?

Comment: (upped) great question spot. I am generally happy when I eat yogurt so hopefully that increases it's health benefits. If I'm in a bad mood I will try to avoid the kitchen in the future ... unless the story is debunked.