# Can people detect "heart waves"?

Tags: psychology, biophysics

A study by Robert McCraty at the "HeartMath Institute" investigates electromagnetic fields created by the human heart and claims:

> Particular emphasis will be devoted to evidence demonstrating that this energy is not only transmitted internally to the brain but is also detectable by others within its range of communication [1]

Can electromagnetc fields generated by a human heart lead to measurable changes in body or brain functions of other people?

[1] [The Energetic Heart: Bioelectromagnetic Communication Within and Between People](http://www.heartmath.org/research/research-publications/energetic-heart-bioelectromagnetic-communication-within-and-between-people.html) - unfortunately, the full text is not freely available.

Comment: given that you normally use expensive devices that are attached directly to the patient to measure heart activity, I'd say that any EM waves leaving the body quickly get drowned in noise and are not normally detectable even if you try

Comment: Possible duplicate of, and/or see also, [Is yogurt affected by human emotions?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/17353/2703) which questions a similar-but-different claim from the same source (i.e. the HeartMath Institute).

Comment: I imagine that you could measure the brain activity of a person observing another person's ECG. I guess this would count as "electromagnetc fields generated by a human heart leading to measurable changes in body or brain functions of other people"